# PHP str_replace with array() gets nested overwriting replaced values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested, str-replace

I want to replace words with tagged words in text.

```
tbl_glossary
id  word
1   apple pie
2   apple
3   juice
```

The words are in array from database (MySQL). Then word gets replaced with replaced word if the word contains the same value (e.g. 'apple pie' contains 'apple').

```
$con = mysqli_connect(db_host, db_username, db_password, db_name);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_glossary`";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $arr_taggedword[] = '<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" id="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['word'].'</a>';
    $arr_word[] = $row['word'];
}

$text = "apple pie made with apple juice";

$results = $text;
foreach($arr_word as $key => $value) {
    $results = str_replace($value, $arr_taggedword[$key], $results);
}
echo $results;
```

Then the result is shown as

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" id="1"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" id="2">apple</a> pie</a> made with <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" id="2">apple</a> <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" id="3">juice</a>
```

'apple pie' is nested.
Any idea to skip/ignore replaced words to get replaced again?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the array form of [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), it will make all your substitutions in order from largest to smallest, but also not replace any text that has already been replaced. Replace your foreach loop with:

```
$results = strtr($text, array_combine($arr_word, $arr_taggedword));
echo $results;
```

Output

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" id="1">apple pie</a> made with <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" id="2">apple</a> <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" id="3">juice</a>
```